# Use Jupyter on VM instance and access BigQuery: "Cannot access Local Host"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine

I have created a VM instance on Google Cloud - Compute Engine. I have installed Jupyter on the instance. I now want to use the notebook to directly query my tables on BigQuery and use the results for analysis.

I am currently doing the following:

```
R = pd.read_gbq(query=Q,project_id = projecti, dialect = 'standard')
R.head()
```

where `Q` is a query I have.

I get the following output:

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbigquery&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=333.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter

  --noauth_local_webserver
```

I try to click the link to authenticate and I get a "Cannot access local host" error.

Comment: Create a service account for your instance to connect to BigQuery on your project.  See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and resolved it by installing `pandas-gbq` using `conda` package manager.

`conda install pandas-gbq --channel conda-forge`

It seems like there is some link missing when `pandas-gbq` is installed via `pip`

Comment: My actual error is that, when I click the link to authenticate, It says "Cannot reach local server". Did you get the same?

Comment: it seems your VM has restricted access

Comment: So how to I change the permissions?

Comment: not sure about that, maybe you need to look into VPC network